# Apache Exec - how to parse quotes?

Tags: command-line, arguments

```
org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine.parse("a b 'c'").getArguments()
```

will return an array with a , b , and c. The quotes (single or double) are removed.

I tried using backslash '\' to escape them but couldn't make it work.

Is there a way to parse the command line using apache CLI that would preserve the quotes?